# [Scala Toolbox]: Compile a Case Class at run-time and then instantiate it

Tags: scala, reflection, tree, compiler-construction, scala-compiler

I'm trying to define a case class using Scala Reflection Toolbox and to instantiate it. What is the best way to do it?

At the moment I do

```
val codeToCompile = q"""case class Authentication(email:String)"""
val tree = toolbox.parse(codeToCompile) 
val classDefinition : ClassDef = tree.asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
val definedClass = toolbox.define(classDefinition)
```

I would like to use the constructor of the case class to instantiate it at run-time after I have defined it into the Toolbox,
Like

```
val codeToCompile = q"""val myAuth = Authentication("test@gmail.com")"""
val tree = toolbox.parse(codeToCompile)
val binary = toolbox.compile(tree)()
```

I get the error: Authentication not found ...
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** `s` interpolator generates strings, `q` interpolator generates trees. So either use `q"..."` without `.parse` or use `s"..."` with `.parse`.

**Secondly,** make use of `ClassSymbol` `definedClass`, which you have.

**Thirdly,** `.apply` is a companion-object method. So use `.companion`.

**Forthly,** there is not much sense in defining a local variable in single-line `q"val x = ???"` with toolbox, anyway it will be hard to use this `TermSymbol` later (on contrary to `ClassSymbol`).

Try

```
val codeToCompile = s"""case class Authentication(email:String)"""
val tree = toolbox.parse(codeToCompile)
val classDefinition : ClassDef = tree.asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
val definedClass = toolbox.define(classDefinition)

val codeToCompile1 = q"""${definedClass.companion}("test@gmail.com")"""
val myAuth = toolbox.eval(codeToCompile1) // Authentication(test@gmail.com)
```